# Who is moving and with who's relation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, relative-motion, inertial-frames

What if we are in a cube of 3×3 m  which is further enclosed in a sphere of radius 50 m? And the sphere start to rotate on its own axis would we experience force? 
If not then what happens if there is a window in the cube and there's nothing else which we can take to reference?

Comment: How is enclosed the cube? Is it tightened to the sphere or is it free? And the sphere is painted on the internal side with different colors to afford assessing the angle by which the sphere rotates?

Comment: It is floating inside the sphere without any gravitational influence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotation is absolute, only uniform paths are inertial. So the answer is yes, the rotating object (which is the sphere in your example) would experience force. The cube would experience no force at all since it is the sphere which is rotating. [1](https://www.google.at/search?q=rotation%20relativity)